# How to get the email message body with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am sending an standard email with Rails like this

```
@mail = mail(to: registration.user.email, subject: "Registration Confirmation: #{@site.name}")
```

Now i need to get the message body (or html in this case) from the email. I tried the following but it does not work since it returns not the rendered email but rather the template (including ERB and Haml).

```
@mail.body
@mail.body.raw_source
@mail.body.encoded
```

It seems surprisingly difficult to do this. I need the result that a persons sees when receiving the email.

**Update**

The ERB and Haml i saw was an HTML comment, that's why in the logs it looked like it logged ERB instead of a rendered tempalte. So @mail.body.encoded works fine.

Comment: If you simply want to have a look at the email body, I think you could use gems like [letter opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about `@mail.body.encoded` (which should give you the result for which you seek)?

Comment: That still returns ERB and HAML in it instead of a rendered email. Like ""<!-- %h1= event_banner_text(@site)"

Comment: @TK-421 Is there a way to get the HTML content only without the header ? I can write a few lines to do so, but if a property exists it will be cleaner.

Answer (score 29):

I tried the accepted answer but it is showing the HEADER along with HTML. To get the HTML tags **only** I've used below code:

```
@mail.html_part.body.decoded
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. First it shows how to use `html_part` (and `text_part`) to get just one or the other. Second it shows `decoded` instead of `encoded`. If you're sending in emails in, say, Japanese, `encoded` gives you Base 64 gibberish, but `decoded` lets you write tests matching against Japanese text.